# Changed vhost and rewrite in CouchDB and can't access the internal API

Tags: couchdb

I wanted to map my custom domain to a design document _rewrite.

```
// Configuration

vhosts     www.myapp.com    /myapp/_design/user/_rewrite

// Rewrites

[{
  "from": "",
  "to": "static/browser/index.html"
}, {
  "from": "*",
  "to": "*"
}]
```

The first route works fine. I can access the index.html with www.myapp.com. However, now I can't access www.myapp.com/_utils. It says _all_dbs can't be found in the browser console. All other APIs stop working as well.

I guess this is because that path is now converted to /myapp/_design/user/_utils.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_utils` and other "special" paths do not cooperate with vhosts very well. Last I checked (version 1.0.2 I think), _utils will display the Futon UI however its AJAX calls to `_all_dbs` and others will fail and it is a total mess.

I suggest a strict separation between your app and your internal management. Use the vhost for the application, but **always avoid vhosts** when accessing Futon or other tools.

There are a few tricks to avoid your vhost.

- Use the server IP address instead of the domain name: `http://1.2.3.4:5984`
- Use a different port if possible: `http://www.myapp.com:5984` or `https://www.myapp.com:6984`
- Add an alternative DNS entry pointing to the same couch and use that: `http://futon.myapp.com`
- Add a dot at the end of your domain. `http://www.myapp.com./` — This is very sneaky (or clever). That is a valid DNS name however CouchDB treats it differently from `www.myapp.com` therefore you will not trigger the vhost.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the couchdb ini file (/etc/couchdb/local.ini), the bind parameter.