# CouchDB vhost rewrite to access root API

Tags: couchdb

I wish the following rewrite rule worked:

```
{
  "from": "api/*",
  "to": "../../../*"
}
```

… in a *vhost* rewrite like the following:

```
[vhosts]
myapp = /myapp/_design/myapp/_rewrite
```

Then it would be possible to access the root API in a following manner:

```js
$.couch.urlPrefix = '/api';

var dbs = $.couch.allDbs({
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

But unfortunately the request to `http://myapp:5984/api/_all_dbs` results into:

```
{"error":"insecure_rewrite_rule","reason":"too many ../.. segments"}
```

Am I missing something? Is something wrong with the rewrite? Does anyone know how to overcome that?
My Couchdb is 1.1.1.

I'm acquainted to [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6641099/133257), but don't like any of the suggested ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
[httpd]
secure_rewrites=false
```

to your server's local.ini to disable this protection from cross-database rewrites.