# How to unlock CouchDB instance on IrisCouch?

Tags: couchdb

I think I've completely stuffed my IrisCouch account!  Futon no longer seems to be responding, and curl produces lots of

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

I suspect it might be due to my efforts to implement URL rewriting.

Futon can be accessed on openoki.iriscouch.org/_utils, but no databases are displayed.  A "loading" image appears next to the title "Overview".

Equally, within Futon, I can click on "Configuration" but no details appear at all.  Instead a "loading" image appears next to the title "Configuration".

Similar responses appear with Status, trying to run a test in the Test Suite (and removing all admins) and with Verify Installation.

With curl:

```
curl -X GET "http://openoki.iriscouch.org/_log"
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Authentication required."}

curl -X GET "http://admin:secret@openoki.iriscouch.org/_log"
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

curl -X GET "http://admin:secret@openoki.iriscouch.org/_config
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

curl -X GET "http://admin:secret@openoki.iriscouch.org/_active_tasks"
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

The last thing that I did was to create a vhost and url rewrite for openoki.iriscouch.org (and .com).  I can no longer access the details, but it was something like

```
{ "from":"",
  "to":"/redgreen/_design/teachers/about.html"
}
```

Any ideas on how I might regain control of this mess?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a programming question. Maybe ask on ServerFault, or, better yet, ask the IrisCouch community/support.

Comment: I have reproduced this issue locally, and it is entirely to do with creating a "root" vhost (in my case for "openoki.iriscouch.com"). So I tried to get the IP address of openoki.iriscouch.com and use that to bypass the virtual host mechanism.  However although I can ping the address, curl and browsers return "Host not found".  Any other suggestions?

Comment: A very similar question was asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640779/changed-vhost-and-rewrite-in-couchdb-and-cant-access-the-internal-api and the accepted answer provides a number of good solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "[secret](https://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/reset_couchdb)" alternative address: iriscou.ch

So I just had to access openoki.iriscou.ch/_utils and remove the vhosts sections I'd added under Configuration.

Comment: `iriscou.ch` not found